# How to generate a variable taking the mean of two other variables?

Tags: average, stata, mean, data-science

I am trying to generate a variable in Stata that is the mean of two other column variables. How can I do this? So far, I have

generate var = mean(var1 var2)

but I know that this is not correct, since mean isn't a command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `mean()` is not a Stata function. No Stata command has that kind of syntax.

To get the mean of two variables, you can just divide their sum by 2:

```
gen var = (var1 + var2)/2
```

If either variable is missing, the result will be missing. If you want to use the non-missing value, you could go

```
gen var = cond(missing(var1, var2), max(var1, var2), (var1 + var2) / 2)
```

or use the `egen` function `rowmean()`.